# Notification not starting a activity in android

Tags: android, service, android-activity, notifications

I am developing a small app in which I want a background service to send a notification and when the user clicks the notification it must launch the appropriate activity. I am posting the code here for the notification and my problem is that the notification gets displayed on the status bar but when i click it it does not launch the activity. Can somebody suggest where I am going wrong. Please help.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        "A New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationService.this,
        com.jeris.android.MetroActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
        .getService(NotificationService.this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(NotificationService.this, "Bullion",
        "Rates for "+ parsedDate+"has not been updated. Go to app to check rates",
        pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(11, notification);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace
`PendingIntent.getService(NotificationService.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

With 
`PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationService.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

Notice the **getService** is replaced with **getActivity**.

Comment: yup i got it...a silly mistake from my side thanks for the help Arun...it works perfectly fine now.

Comment: Modifying the target Activity's manifest definition and adding *android:exported="true"* within "activity" tags for the target Activity worked for me in the case of "notification built in service not starting target activity".

Comment: @mass ,@Arun George I used this in my FCM service it open intented activity if app already has opened else it open startup activity with getIntent().getExtras() that is null.i tried android:exported="true" on intented activity but not worked.any idea?