# Creating a notification that opens the Activity for Android API 10

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification that when clicked opens the activity I've defined for it to open, I know this is a duplicate question, but I've tried if not everything, most of the things that are on this page that would help to correct this error and it still doesn't open the activity when the notification is pressed, I mean I've checked things like the ones shown on these links:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081414/notification-not-starting-a-activity-in-android) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743998/clicking-on-notification-is-not-starting-intended-activity) [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886136/create-notification-for-api-10)

Along with some others and the notification still doesn't open the activity when the notification is pressed.

So, I'd like to ask for a code that has been checked that actually works properly in a physical device with Android API 10, or at least some tips that have been checked on that particular API

I'm giving my actual code relating to the notification:

```
   private void SetNotification(String title, String ContentText)
        {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentTitle(giveStringAccordingtoLanguage(title)) 
                            .setContentText(giveStringAccordingtoLanguage(ContentText));

            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            builder.setSound(alarmSound);
            builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

            Intent targetIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity4.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 72);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml the activity is defined as:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.atg.myapplication4.MainActivity4"
        android:label="Application"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

On the other hand I've checked that this code:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);


    Intent i = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0);

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_icon,"OK",pIntent);
    // This intent is fired when notification is clicked
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Large icon appears on the left of the notification


    // Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
    builder.setContentTitle("dsd");

    // Content text, which appears in smaller text below the title
    builder.setContentText("cxzcsd");

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(alarmSound);
    // The subtext, which appears under the text on newer devices.
    // This will show-up in the devices with Android 4.2 and above only
    builder.setSubText("Tap to go to link in notifications.");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Will display the notification in the notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(12345, builder.build());
```

does somehow what I'm trying to do, but instead of opening MainActivity4.class with opening the url on the browser.

If I try to change the line Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/")); for Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity4.class); or Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity4.class); it doesn't work. So which would be the correct way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it still doesn't work" and "still doesn't work as expected" means. Also, please get rid of the `sleep()` call.

Comment: Done, hope it's more clear.

Comment: Try getting rid of `setVibrate()`, and perhaps `setSound()`. IOW, cut this back to `setSmallIcon()`, `setContentTitle()`, and `setContentIntent()`. Then (after getting rid of the `sleep()` call), see if you have better luck. For example, `setVibrate()` requires that your app request the `VIBRATE` permission.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, I've edited my question to share something that might help to solve the problem.

Comment: Check LogCat for warnings/errors from the system when you tap the notification to try starting `MainActivity4`.

Comment: No error appears, anyway I managed to find a workaround, so for the user it's the same. I'm posting it now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manged to solve the issue with this code:

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent LaunchIntent = null;
    String apppack = "com.example.atg.myapplication4";
    String name = "";
    try {
        if (pm != null) {
            ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(apppack, 0);
            name = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(app);
            LaunchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apppack);
        }
        Toast.makeText(context,"Found it:" + name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = LaunchIntent; // new Intent();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);


    Intent i = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0);

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_icon,"OK",pIntent);
    // This intent is fired when notification is clicked

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Large icon appears on the left of the notification


    // Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
    builder.setContentTitle("dsd");

    // Content text, which appears in smaller text below the title
    builder.setContentText("cxzcsd");

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(alarmSound);
    // The subtext, which appears under the text on newer devices.
    // This will show-up in the devices with Android 4.2 and above only
    builder.setSubText("Tap to go to link in notifications.");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Will display the notification in the notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(12345, builder.build());
```

I wonder why it won't work by calling the activity, but after having spent more than 8 hours with this issue I'm satisfied with this solution